# iOS 11 - SplitViewController Master Navigation Table View Changes Status Bar Color When DisplayMode.primaryHidden changed to .allVisible

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uisplitviewcontroller

Hopefully this will save someone else from spending 4 hours debugging this problem.

I added a master tableview hiding feature to my splitviewcontroller when the list that populates it is empty.

The list starts out empty, and then is populated from the network.

```
class RootViewController: UISplitViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.05, green: 0.14, blue: 0.38, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
}

@objc func displayTableView(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320
    self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible
}

@objc func hideTableView(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.primaryHidden
}
```

This code worked to hide/show the tableview, but the result was that the navigation bar colour on the table view was different from the status bar ONLY above the status bar.

What solved the problem for me was adding

```
self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible
```

to the `viewWillAppear` function of the SplitViewController as an initializer.

Comment: You may also animate the `preferredDisplayMode ` property. `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible }`

Answer (score 0):

**Full Solution:**

```
class RootViewController: UISplitViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.05, green: 0.14, blue: 0.38, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
}

@objc func displayTableView(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320
    self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible
}

@objc func hideTableView(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.primaryHidden
}
```